# node how to access an object globally

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am learning node js. so as an exercise i want to use twit to interact with the twitter api.
i login with twitter, and get back the access token and secret, on my main file ( server.ts ), i log it, and get the right credentials.
then i store it in locals ( which i read is the way to make global variables in node, which is crazy) and then, when i want to use in in another route file i get the error: ReferenceError: Tobj is not defined

this is how i instantiate the object:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
consumerKey: 'myconsumerkey',
consumerSecret: 'myconsumersecret',
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4000/twitter/return'
},(token,tokenSecret,profile,callback) => {

twitterconfig.access_token = token;
twitterconfig.access_token_secret = tokenSecret;
app.locals.Tobj = new Twit(twitterconfig);

return callback(null,profile);
}));
```

then in my user routes file i try to log it:

```
//profile route
router.get('/profile', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('profile: ',Tobj);
    res.send('profile page')
});
```

and so, i get the error. so how can i use the twitter object outside of that specific scope? i thought all i have to do is use the locals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `locals` through the `req`, such as:

```
router.get('/profile', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('profile: ', req.app.locals.Tobj);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate module in another file where you can get or set the twitter config. Then use it

In twitterconfig.js (for example)

```
var twitconfig = null;

module.exports.setConfig = function(config) {
    twitconfig = config;
};

module.exports.getConfig = function() {
    return twitconfig;
};
```

Then when you keed to set or get it from another module, require twitterconfig.js.

```
var myconfig = require(’./twitterconfig.js’);

console.log(”config: ” + myconfig.getConfig());
```

So, simple module for storing the config for later use. The benefit is that you can more easily also unit test your design.